# How to pick out terms in a linear equation with a positive coefficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation

Basically I have a really large output which looks like a long linear equation

$AAA-BAA-CAA+DAA+...-ZZZ$

And I only am concerned about those terms that have a positive coefficient (i.e. a plus in front). The others I can ignore.

How can I get mathematica to ignore those positive-coefficient terms, or at the very least order the list such that the negative coefficient terms are in the front (or back).

Comment: `aaa - bbb + ccc + dd - eee /. Times[-1, __] :> Sequence[]`?

Comment: @kguler Wow, works like a charm! Thanks! But I can't parse it easily, how does it work?

Comment: i posted a simpler solution. Regarding how it works, please see [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and [PatternTest](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html) in the docs for many examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expr = aaa - 3 bbb + ccc + ddd - eee
expr /. _?Negative :> 0
(* aaa + ccc + ddd *)
```